# Enumerating generic structs

Tags: generics, struct, rust

I wanted to try to build a proper implementation of Peano numbers using `struct`s, but it seems my generics game is not good enough yet and I could use some help. I read the docs on generics and [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30942408/casting-to-a-generic-type) [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28589764/returning-and-using-a-generic-type-with-match) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29184358/requiring-implementation-of-mul-in-generic-function), but they don't fit my case.

I introduced a `Peano` trait and `Zero` and `Succ` types:

```
trait Peano {}

struct Zero;
struct Succ<T: Peano>(T);
```

And implemented a `Peano` trait for both types to be able to abstract over both:

```
impl Peano for Zero {}
impl<T> Peano for Succ<T> where T: Peano {}
```

At first I wanted to implement `std::ops::Add` for `Peano`, but I quickly saw that I was doing something very wrong, so I decided to start with something simpler - enumeration:

```
trait Enumerate<T: Peano> {
    fn succ(&self) -> Succ<T>;
    fn pred(&self) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<T> Enumerate<T> for Zero where T: Peano {
    fn succ(&self) -> Succ<T> { Succ(*self) } // mismatched types: Zero instead of T
    fn pred(&self) -> Option<T> { None }
}

impl<T> Enumerate<T> for Succ<T> where T: Peano {
    fn succ(&self) -> Succ<T> { Succ(*self) } // mismatched types: Succ<T> instead of T
    fn pred(&self) -> Option<T> { Some(self.0) }
}
```

What am I missing? I experimented with boxing the results (though I would want to avoid that if possible), but the error just changed to `mismatched types: Box<Succ<T>> instead of Box<Peano>`, so I'm not sure this is helpful.

Full code below:

```
trait Peano {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
struct Zero;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
struct Succ<T: Peano>(T);

impl Peano for Zero {}
impl<T> Peano for Succ<T> where T: Peano {}

trait Enumerate<T: Peano> {
    fn succ(&self) -> Succ<T>;
    fn pred(&self) -> Option<T>;
}

impl<T> Enumerate<T> for Zero where T: Peano {
    fn succ(&self) -> Succ<T> { Succ(*self) }
    fn pred(&self) -> Option<T> { None }
}

impl<T> Enumerate<T> for Succ<T> where T: Peano {
    fn succ(&self) -> Succ<T> { Succ(*self) }
    fn pred(&self) -> Option<T> { Some(self.0) }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `T` in `Enumerate`... which serves no purpose.

If you look back at your `Peano` trait, you will see that it has no `T`: the implementation for `Succ` has a parameter, but the trait itself does not.

The same applies here.

Let us start with a reduced scope: an `Enumerate` that can only go forward.

```
use std::marker::Sized;

trait Peano {}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
struct Zero;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy, PartialEq)]
struct Succ<T: Peano>(T);

impl Peano for Zero {}
impl<T> Peano for Succ<T> where T: Peano {}

trait Enumerate: Peano + Sized {
    fn succ(self) -> Succ<Self>;
}

impl Enumerate for Zero {
    fn succ(self) -> Succ<Self> { Succ(self) }
}

impl<T> Enumerate for Succ<T> where T: Peano {
    fn succ(self) -> Succ<Succ<T>> { Succ(self) }
}
```

A few points of interest:

- you can refer to the current type as `Self`, very useful when defining a trait since the type of implementers is unknown in advance
- you can constrain the implementers of a trait by using the `: Peano + Sized` syntax after the trait name

---

Now, you also had a `prev` method which I did not implement. The thing is, it is nonsensical to apply `prev` to `Zero`. In this case, I propose that you rename `Enumerate` to `Next` and I'll show how to create a `Prev` trait:

```
trait Prev: Peano + Sized {
    type Output: Peano + Sized;
    fn prev(self) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<T> Prev for Succ<T> where T: Peano {
    type Output = T;
    fn prev(self) -> Self::Output { self.0 }
}
```

The syntax `type Output: Peano + Sized` is an *associated type*, it allows each implementer to specify which type to use for their specific case (and avoid having the *user* of the trait, having to guess which type they should use).

Once specified, it can be referred to as `Self::Output` within the trait or as `<X as Prev>::Output` from outside (if `X` implements `Prev`).

And since the trait is separate, you only have a `Prev` implementation for `Peano` numbers that actually *have* a predecessor.

---

Why the `Sized` constraint?

At the moment, Rust requires that return types have a known size. This is an implementation limit: in practice the caller has to reserve enough space on the stack for the callee to write down the return value.

However... for type-level computation this is useless! So, what do we do?

Well, first we add convenient method of checking the result of our computations (prettier than the `Debug` output):

```
trait Value: Peano {
    fn value() -> usize;
}

impl Value for Zero {
    fn value() -> usize { 0 }
}

impl<T> Value for Succ<T> where T: Value {
    fn value() -> usize { T::value() + 1 }
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Succ::<Zero>::value());
}
```

Then... let's get rid of those methods, they bring nothing; the reworked traits are thus:

```
trait Next: Peano {
    type Next: Peano;
}

impl Next for Zero {
    type Next = Succ<Zero>;
}

impl<T> Next for Succ<T> where T: Peano {
    type Next = Succ<Succ<T>>;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", <Zero as Next>::Next::value());
}
```

and:

```
trait Prev: Peano {
    type Prev: Peano;
}

impl<T> Prev for Succ<T> where T: Peano {
    type Prev = T;
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", <<Zero as Next>::Next as Prev>::Prev::value());
}
```

Now, you can go ahead and implement `Add` and co, though if you implement traits with methods you might need additional constraints.

Comment: And thanks for the additional information regarding type-level computation - my trait-foo has improved a lot.

Comment: @ljedrz: I would note that if you want to go "deep" into type level computation, you might be interested in the [typenum](https://crates.io/crates/typenum) crate.